# HTTP authentication in IDE cloud9

Tags: node.js, ide, cloud9-ide

Does anyone knows how to setup an authentication of cloud9 IDE. I'd like to have an authentication so that the source codes would not access publicly and it should be logged in before can touch the source codes.

P.S. I already have cloud9 own my network and it is working very well.

Answer (score -1):

Easiest way is to plug into the connect plugin in cloud9 and add connect auth middleware to do basic authentication there. As far as I know there are no public extensions available that do this for you but some devs have added this to their own projects.

**edit** Nowadays Cloud9 comes with built in basic authentication (in commit [cf98892](https://github.com/ajaxorg/cloud9/commit/cf98892a8979709aa18f1b18df333bb827b783bf#README.md))